# multi re-rendering by `use` of react 18.3.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to fetch and suspense use by `use` of react 18.3.0, but occurred multi re-rendering.

- react: 18.3.0-canary-3ff846d10-20230724
- next: 13.4.12

This code is `render SuspenseTest` output to the console multiple times (about 5 to 8 times) until render `Done`.

```
// src/pages/index.tsx

import { Suspense } from "react"

import Head from "next/head"

import SuspenseTest from "@/components/modules/SuspenseTest"

const Top = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Suspense Test</title>
      </Head>
      <main>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Now Loading...</div>}>
          <SuspenseTest />
        </Suspense>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Top
```

```
// src/components/modules/SuspenseTest/index.tsx

import { use } from "react"

const fetcher = (): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Done")
    }, 5000),
  )

  // What I actually want to do is the following process
  // return axiosClient
  //   .get("/articles")
  //   .then((response) => {
  //     return response.data as Promise<Article[]>
  //   })
  //   .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}

const SuspenseTest = (): JSX.Element => {
  console.log("render SuspenseTest")

  const message = use<string>(fetcher())

  return <div>{message}</div>
}

export default SuspenseTest
```

I expected only once rendering.

I tried use `React.memo`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`, but that doesn't seem to be the point (maybe).

I would like to avoid using external libraries as much as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-worker-swmp5v?file=/src/App.js

```js
const p = fetcher();
const SuspenseTest = () => {
  console.log("render SuspenseTest");

  const message = use(p);

  return <div>{message}</div>;
};
```

**TL; DR;
The promise returned by fetcher should be cached.**

### Explanation:

Let me explain the mechanism of `React.use`:

First render: When `use` is being called with a promise, React would stop rendering and wait for the promise to resolve.

Second render: When the promise is resolved, React would render the component again.

Now in React's developers' perspective, a difficult scenario appears: That component may render again. The next time it renders, you can stop taking care of the promise. But then, what if a developer actually change something in the promise and actually need it to be resolved again?

The answer is, React will at least render a component with `use` twice, then determine whether another render is needed by comparing the promise passed to `use` during previous render and this render.

If it does not change, then React will do nothing. It will continue to render the remaining parts.

If it changes, then it means developer changes something. OK, one additional render is scheduled.

The general implementation would be like:

```js
let prev = null;
function use(p) {
  if (p === prev) {
    return;
  }
  prev = p;
  p.then(() => renderThisComponentAgain());
}
```

So coming back to your problem. What happens in my sample implementation?

First render, `use` is called, p is handled by React. It waits for p to resolve.

When p resolves, the second render is triggered. At the same `use`, React find that new p equals to the previous one. Great, it continues to render.

What happens in your implementation?

First render, `use` is called, p is handled by React. It waits for p to resolve.

When p resolves, the second render is triggered. At the same `use`, React find that another p is passed to `use`. OK, it waits for the second p to resolve.

When p resolves, the 3rd render is triggered.

When p resolves, the 4rd render is triggered.

...

Infinite loop.

Disclaimer: My explanation does not come from the actual implementation, but you can understand it in that way.